Format of Select2 Option HTML drop down
I am seeing something I can't explain.  I am using Select2 for a searchable drop down field.  I am trying to configure the options with a different string for the value as opposed to the text.  I would like to have the text be a UUID string and the value be a simple string.  The example is:
<option value="eb73dbb6-ed12-49d5-90d5-87dcfe0c462a">BATG</option>

I am building the options dynamically in javascript.  However, I do not get the 'BATG' tag in the field when I select the option from the drop down.  As an experiment I swapped the value and the text in this example:
<option value="BATG">eb73dbb6-ed12-49d5-90d5-87dcfe0c462a</option>

And to my surprise I got the expected result with a formatted tag with the UUID.
I have checked with phind.com and googled and I have found nothing that restricts the value in Select2 in the documentation.

Because the value for a select comes from the selected option as you discovered, which is how a select works when submitted. If you want the text that the user sees in the list instead, then you can get that by doing: $("#myselect option:selected").text();

Thanks but that is not the issue.  When the value of the option is "BATG" the UUID is presented as the tag in the field -- as expected.  But when the value is the UUID there is no tag in the field for the option.  So the issue is not with the value it is about what is presented in the select field.

HTML also has the <option label=""> attribute as an alternative to using the textContent of the <opton> element for display-text. I don't know how well Select2 handles it though. (Also it's 2024 now: no-one needs to be using jQuery for anything).

Found the issue.  My experiment hide the issue that the select has to be the value.  Once I select the values (the uuid) everything worked.
